# Split Data operator in RapidMiner generates always the same splits

Tags: rapidminer

I am using RapidMiner Studio 7.0.001 on Mac OSX platform.
While using Split Data operator, I recognized that it always generates the same splits for my data. I didn't use local random seed and all the sampling types have the same problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top level process, there is a parameter called `random seed`. Set this to `-1` to cause a new random seed to be generated from the system time. Make sure the parameter `use local random seed` in the `Split Data` operator is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks awchisholm. Your advice resolved the problem.